# creating a css grid with css clear:both and nth of type

Tags: html, css

here is my code
http://jsfiddle.net/wahidpolin/b9j6ktfq/

```css
li{
 display:inline-block;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 float:left;
 }
li:nth-of-type(3n+1){
 background-color: yellow;
 clear:both;
 }
```

```html
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
<li>11</li>
<li>12</li>
```

in my understanding 1,4,7,10 should have been in a single line as i've declared clear:both to them,but it's not,what's going on here?

Comment: the `clear` property only takes into account the preceding elements. The `both` value means apply clear whether the previous elements were floated `left` or `right`. See the docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear#Values

Comment: i didn't know about the preceding element thing,thnx

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/dq8c66oc/

Was this what you where looking for?

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  float: left;
}
li:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
  float: none;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
<li>11</li>
<li>12</li>
```

---

Edit:

How this works is that the yellow blocks are not inline-blocks. Meaning that they push every sibling element below it on the given page. Float none makes sure that any floating elements won't interact with the block. Clear both makes it so that any previous floating elements are cleared before rendering the div.

Comment: sorry i don't need any solutions,i just need an explanation about how it's working

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, but not so sweet

```
li{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    float:left;
}
li:nth-of-type(3n+1){
    background-color: yellow;
    clear:both;
}
li:nth-of-type(3n+2){
    clear:both;
}
```